# Correct exercise extension

Tags: exercise, muscle, lower-back

I am getting a bit confused with extension exercises, e.g. Back Extension and Glute extension. I don't have a specific machine, so I improvise using my normal bench to do it.

What is the difference between the two? Right now, I keep my body up to my pelvis on the bench and do the extension. Do I need to keep my lower back on the bench too? I think that will round my back, which I saw on the internet is bad.

Can you please advise how to do a correct back extension so that hip flexion does not come in to play?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two is which part of your body is lifting. In a back extension, you're lifting your torso off the surface of where you are lying. In a glute extension, you are lifting the legs up.

However, this does not seem to entirely match what you are describing above, so since you mention keeping your back on the bench, I'll assume you're doing this supine rather than prone, which would correspond more to a [leg lift](https://www.womenshealthmag.com/fitness/leg-lifts).

As regards rounding of the back, I think you're confusing a rounded back with a flat back. The latter is what you're aiming for.